# MYSQL: Deadlock with simple queries

Tags: php, mysql, deadlock

I have a table 'clicks', where I add the record every time user navigates special counter script click.php. This table does not have an autoincrement column, it's has `transaction_id CHAR(32)` as primary key, which is generated randomly before inserting a new record. Each new record has column `normalized=0`.

Every 3 minutes background daemon starts a transaction, reads all new clicks `WHERE normalized=0` and groups it to table `stats`. The only write-query for that table is `UPDATE clicks SET normalized=1 WHERE normalized=0` executed at the end of all processing and then transaction commits.

Problem is that every time when click.php is navigated during this transaction, the script can not add a new record to 'clicks' and fails with error:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 
1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

    INSERT  `clicks` 
    SET `transaction_id`='3520359d597ba05b635ff15feb334229',
        `time`='2016-04-29 15:14:31', 
        ...,
        `normalized`='0'
```

I know that I can solve this using `LOCK TABLES`, but I just want to know why this deadlock occurs.

UPD:
I see following reason in SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output:

```
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 252763 page no 124 n bits 480 index `normalized` 
of table `tds`.`clicks` trx id C1329EF lock_mode X locks gap before 
rec insert intention waiting
```

Answer (score 0):

(this should be a comment, but its long and involved)

What's the transaction isolation mode?

I've never come across this before - mostly because I avoid using mutli-statement transactions, e.g.

```
UPDATE clicks 
SET normalized=2
WHERE normalized=0; 

INSERT INTO stats (transaction_id, clicks)
SELECT transaction_id, COUNT(*)
FROM clicks 
WHERE normalized=2
GROUP BY transaction_id;

UPDATE clicks
SET transaction_id=1
WHERE transaction_id=2;
```

There are ways of doing this with a single update to the clicks table if you use a seperate column and a generated identifier for the dataset. And if you're running this from cron you should probably wrap these in a GET_LOCK()...RELEASE_LOCK() cycle to prevent concurrency. Although the model does support concurrency for most transaction models, its a bit of a performance hit when things are already going bad.